# Copy formulas without a cell reference change

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open a workbook and then copy a column to another workbook side by side (column from each file adjacent to each other).
However I do not want to change the cell reference (i.e. if refrence in range being copied is C15:C17 i do not want it to move). How could I approach this?

Currently I am using the following code:

```
Sub dane_wolne()
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Wiersz2 = 20

For i = 1 To Wiersz2
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=Katalog & "U" & i & ".xlsx", ReadOnly:=True


    Range("D11:D210").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obliczenia").Range("E11:E210").Offset(0, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas


    Workbooks("U" & i & ".xlsx").Close
Next i
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't want the reference to move then can you use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obliczenia").Range("D11:D210")` instead of `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obliczenia").Range("E11:E210")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Range.Formula property

You can use:
`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obliczenia").Range("E11:E210").Offset(0, i).Formula = Range("D11:D210").Formula`

Copy formats in separate step.

### Off topic tips

Make the `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obliczenia").Range("E11:E210")` a range variable once, then apply just `.Offset` to make your code a bit cleaner and faster (nanoseconds :))

Aslo, it is a good practice to set the new opened workbook into a variable, to make it more explicit and reliable. E.g.: `Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open FileName:=Katalog & "U" & i & ".xlsx", ReadOnly:=True` (Not always necessary.)
Then use the `SourceWB.Range("D11:D210")`

Comment: There is no need to add the `SourceWB` part with the implementation of this code, since the `ActiveWorkbook` is automatically set to the Workbook you open, and therefore Range("D11:D210") is automatically assigned to `ActiveWorkBook` (which is the Workbook you just opened)

Comment: @ShaiRado Agreed. It's just a good pracitce. For example some other code (event) could change the ActiveWorkbook to different workbook, hence copying a wrong range. But as you said, no NEED in this implementation.